# Powershell array needed, not sure how to do this, looking for guidance

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a text file that has many instances of 10 lines per object. I will like to scan these 10 lines to check if status=failure then pull in Account ID for that failure. Here is a sample of text file:

```
AccountID                 : 123_123
Safe                      : test1
address                   : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
userName                  : frank
name                      : frank@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
platformId                : test
secretType                : password
platformAccountProperties : @{Location=home; Owner=Me; Function=switch; Type=user; Port=22}
secretManagement          : @{automaticManagementEnabled=True; status=success; lastModifiedTime=1590499693}
createdTime               : 5/26/2020 1:28:13 PM

AccountID                 : 321_321
Safe                      : test2
address                   : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
userName                  : ralph
name                      : ralph@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
platformId                : test
secretType                : password
platformAccountProperties : @{Location=home; Owner=Me; Function=switch; Type=user; Port=22}
secretManagement          : @{automaticManagementEnabled=False; manualManagementReason=(CPM)MaxRetries; status=failure; lastModifiedTime=1590499684}
createdTime               : 5/26/2020 1:28:04 PM
```

Notice on secretManagement line status=failure, I need to scan each section to pull down AccountID for that failure, I have tried several ways to do this but I get no luck on it as I am not constructing it correctly. Any ideas on how to do this correctly?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may take the [Tour] and read the help for [Ask] to set your expectations on SO. Regarding to your task you could watch the great video from Dr.Tobias Weltner about [Sophisitcated Techniques of Plain Text Parsing](https://youtu.be/Hkzd8spCfCU).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

I believe that the following script should work provided that the formatting in your example is always the same.

```bsh
# Read the file content.
$fileContent = Get-Content C:\tmp\overflow\63004109\data.txt
# Remove all empty lines from the array.
$fileContent = $fileContent | ? { $_ -ne "" }

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $fileContent.Length; $i++) {
  $obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject

  for ($x = $i; $x -lt ($i+10); $x++) {
    $splt = $fileContent[$x].Split(":")

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $splt[0].Trim() -Value $splt[1].Trim()
  }

  # Check if the 'secretManagement' status was a 'failure'.
  if (($obj.secretManagement -replace '@{','' -replace '}','' -replace '; ',"`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData).Status -eq "failure") {
    # Here is where you want to do something with the accounts that failed.
    $obj.AccountID + ": " + ($obj.secretManagement -replace '@{','' -replace '}','' -replace '; ',"`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData).Status
  }
  $i += 9
}
```

Comment: This works!! I almost had it like you had it it and I knew I was missing a few pieces, thanks again!!!!!